# INDESIGN: How to align text vertically to the top of a tall line

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, footnotes

Please see attached image. I have notes that are numbered, some include images.
Notes 14 and 15 are sitting at the bottom of the line, How do I get them to sit at the top like 16 and 17?
[image: Notes 14 and 15 are sitting at the bottom of the line, How do I get them to sit at the top like 16 and 17?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your images are anchored objects, there are two ways to do it, depending on their positional type; one is easier to automate than the other.

Note that you’re looking at it backwards: it’s the *image* you want to align to the top of the paragraph, not the other way around.

### With custom positioning

The most automatable way is by using *Custom Positioning*, because this way you can let InDesign do the necessary calculations, which means you can save it in an object style.

- Select one of the images you want to top-align. Open the *Object Styles* panel and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to create a new object style, then double-click the new style to apply and edit it. It may bring over effects, size constrictions, etc. from the selected image, so make sure to disable any properties you don’t want to apply to all the top-aligned images.
- Click on the left-side menu item *Anchored Object Options* in the dialog that opens, and make sure your options look like this:

[image: Object Style Options – Anchored Object Options]

*Anchored Object → Reference point* should be the top left corner; *Anchored Position → Reference Point* should be the left point; *X Relative To* should be *Anchor Marker* and 0 mm; *Y Relative To* should be *Line (Top of Leading)* and 0 mm.

- Click on the left-side menu item *Text Wrap & Other* and make sure text wrap is set to *Jump Object* (fourth option from the left).
- Give your style an appropriate name (I called mine *Top-aligned image* in the screenshot) and click *OK* to save it.
- Apply this object style to all the images you want to align to the top of the paragraph.

### With inline positioning

If you want to keep the images as having inline position, I don’t think there’s an automated way to do it. You need to refer to the height of the image, so you can’t save it as an object style, but have to do it manually per image.

- Select an image you want to top-align; note the height of the image and the paragraph leading.
- Set the image’s text wrap to *Jump Object* (this can be an object style).
- Right-click on the image and select *Anchored Object* → *Options…* and make sure your settings are set thus:

  - *Position* is set to *Inline Or Above Line*
  - *Inline* is selected
  - *Y Offset* is set to `-[image height] + [leading]`; e.g., if your image is 40 mm in height and your paragraph leading is 14 pt, write `-40mm + 14pt` in the input box
- Click *OK* to apply and repeat for each image you want to top-align.

Comment: Hi THere. THank you So much for taking the time to write this. Option 1 would be great but the images overlap so it doesn't space out the notes correctly.

Comment: @ReuvenCentner Did you remember to set the text wrap to _Jump Object_? That should prevent the overlapping. At least in normally flowed text – I didn’t test in actual footnotes (which behave differently to regular flowed text), so if your notes are actually footnotes, that may be the problem.

Comment: Yes it is set as that. We're using the Id-extras.com Footwork  script which allows us to have 2 columns of footnotes for 1 body of text

Comment: I discovered my problem. I was using baseline grid which was messing up the alignment. THis answer is good. Thank you!!!